Passing object values between modules in Outlook VBA
I have 6 mailboxes configured in Outlook (x64 365 v 2411), 2x Exchange and 4x MAPI. If is clicked on New Email in the Outlook ribbon, a form is dieplayed where the user can shoose for a Dutch or English message. By default the sender is based on the current selected mailbox in Outlook.
Currently in ThisOutlookSession:
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents objInsp As Outlook.Inspectors
Public objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub objInsp_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If TypeName(Inspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then
        Set objMailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
        Load frmNewEmail
        With frmNewEmail
            .StartUpPosition = 2
            .Show False
        End With
    End If
End Sub

So far no issues, the form is displayed when New Email is clicked. However, after btnEnglish is clicked:
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnEnglish_Click()
    Me.hide
    Call MyNewMessage(2)
    Unload Me
End Sub

The expected behavior is that objMailItem still holds the value when the next procedure is started in Modules > MyFunctions:
Option Explicit
Public objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

Public Sub MyNewMessage(lngLangID As Long)
    Dim objMsg As Object
    Dim strSigID As String

    AddTable objMailItem

    strSigID = GetSignatureID(objMailItem, lngLangID)

    VerifySignature objMailItem, strSigID

    With objMailItem
        .Subject = "[Case No. 000000] "
    End With

    frmNewEmail.hide
    Unload frmNewEmail
    Set objMailItem = Nothing
End Sub

Here I notice that objMailItem does not have a value any longer. I tried to use objMailItem as form tag and pass it from there, but also there objMailItem has no value. Trying for hours with alternative options did not help.
How can I maintain the value of objMailItem and pass it on to procedures in other forms and modules?
Art.

You can avoid the global variable and pass the mail item directly to your userform:
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents objInsp As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub objInsp_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    Dim frm As frmNewEmail, msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeName(Inspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then
        Set frm = New frmNewEmail 'avoid using the default instance...
        With frm
            Set .Message = Inspector.CurrentItem 'pass message directly to userform
            .StartUpPosition = 2
            .Show False
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Add a Message Property to your userform:
Option Explicit

Private m_msg As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub btnEnglish_Click()
    Me.hide
    MyNewMessage m_msg, 2 'use of Call is deprecated
    Unload Me
End Sub

'called from the code launching the form
Property Set Message(v As Outlook.MailItem)
    Set m_msg = v
End Property

Edit MyNewMessage to add the message reference as a parameter:
Public Sub MyNewMessage(msg As Outlook.MailItem, lngLangID As Long)
    'work with msg and lngLangID 
End Sub


Thx Tim. I would never come up with that idea. I tried to pass the variable using the tag property of the form, but this is of a different type. The "Message" property is, as I understand it, a custom property that can be assigned to a form, for which you can use any name. Searching for some additional info I found this page https://peltiertech.com/Excel/PropertyProcedures.html which further explains it in some more detail. I tested your suggestions and it works. Much appreciated!

Yes - it doesn't have to be called Message - you could use any name.  Good to hear it worked out.

Excellent. However, I have a new issue (GetInspector error) when I try to make this userform modal to have it always displayed on top of the new message. I appreciate if you can have a quick look at it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79103795/getinspector-on-a-non-displayed-mailitem-outlook-vba

You independently declare objMailItem in two different modules. These are two independent variables.

Thx Dmirty. Yes is a reason that explains why the variable isn't passed on, or the other reason I was assuming that a new declaration would reset the other one.  It is just the use of the form that was troubling me and for a good reason, having read the explanation on the page https://peltiertech.com/Excel/PropertyProcedures.html.
