GetInspector on a non displayed MailItem
OK, now the passing of variables in my previous post is resolved, a new issue came up.
Clicking the New Email button triggers the routine that displays the userform immediately followed by the actual mail message. However, the new message is displayed on top of the userform. Workable, but not ideal.
Private Sub objInsp_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    Dim frm As frmNewEmail
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeName(Inspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then
        If Inspector.CurrentItem.Subject <> "" Then
            Exit Sub 'This procedure is only for new email mesages
        End If
        Set frm = New frmNewEmail
        With frm
            Set .Message = Inspector.CurrentItem
            .StartUpPosition = 2
            .Show False
        End With
    End If
End Sub

A simple solution was to make the user form modal (removing the False option after .Show). Indeed, only the userform is now displayed, and I assume the email message window is waiting on the userform to be unloaded. At least, that was what I would expect.
After a language is clicked in the userform, the userform is hidden, unloaded and the procedure MyNewEmail is executed, which start several other procedures.
However, my code now throws an error while executing these procedures at Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector, while with a non modal userform the code is executed without errors. I read on some forums that GetInspector is to be called on a mailitem that is displayed. However, any attempt to display the mail message results in an error as well.
The problematic code is in this: (objItem is
If msg.Class = olMail Then
    Set objInsp = msg.GetInspector '<<< Throws an error if userform = Modal
    If objInsp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
        If objInsp.CurrentItem.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            objInsp.CurrentItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        End If
    End If
Else
    Exit Function
End If

There are several options which I can think of, but none of the code I worked with resolved this error.
a)  Make the inspector window of the new message visible (and hope this helps). However, I was not able to identify the or window.
b)  Execute the user form in a non-modal mode and minimise the new email window. I tried Application.ActiveWindow.WindowState = olMinimized, but in this case, the main Outlook window was minimized (the message window hasn't been displayed yet).
c)  …?
Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Can you call msg.GetInspector before displaying the modal form?

Instead of passing msg to the userform you could try passing Inspector.   Can't test for a while...

If the function of the user form is only to choose a language, it doesn’t need to know about the message at all: it can just return the selected language…

I got the solution!

Tim, you’re right that the form does not need to pass on the mailitem object. Just open the form and let it return a value based on the user choice in the form.
The problem was that GetInspector is only possible when the Inspector window is displayed. The problem occurred while opening the modal form because the process of NewInspector stopped pending execution of the procedures called before the actual message was displayed. Opening the form non modal did not interfere with the NewInspector procedure. Because some procedures included modification of the message body (which needed GetInspector), such procedures are only available after the event Inspector.Activate (See example on https://www.vboffice.net/en/developers/newinspector-and-inspector-activate/)

The adjusted procedures are:
Private WithEvents objOpenInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Private WithEvents objInsp As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub objInsp_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
    If TypeName(Inspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then
        Set objOpenInsp = Inspector
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub objOpenInsp_Activate()
    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim frm As frmLanguage
    Dim lngLang As Long
    
    Set objItem = objOpenInsp.CurrentItem
    If Len(objItem.EntryID) = 0 And Len(objItem.Subject) = 0 Then 
        'This procedure is only for new email messages. 
        'Note that if you leave the subject line empty and try to close
        'the objItem window, the Activate event is triggered too and may 
        'get stuck in a loop.
        Set frm = New frmLanguage
        frm.Show
        lngLang = frm.lngRetValue
        Unload frm
        If lngLang > 0 Then
            'MyNewMessage Inspector.CurrentItem, lngLang
            MyNewMessage objItem, lngLang
        Else 'User pressed Cancel or closed the form
            objItem.Subject = " " 'prevent loop
            objItem.Close olDiscard
        End If
    End If
    Set frm = Nothing
    Set objItem = Nothing
End Sub

Again, thx for your help!

Good to see you found a solution.
